# Azure AD login take long time when first time login

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using Azure AD single sign-on in the ASP.Net Core 6 application.
In production when doing first-time login it's taking a long time compared with thereafter.

Please give me suggestions to improve the speed.

Note: Only one web application is used for Azure AD

Comment: Do you have any concern about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We need to [ensure the application pool is always running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64854145/7687666), this can fix the issue.

There are 2 option in start mode, OnDemand and AlwaysRunning. The default value for idle time-out is 20 minutes. It means if there is no http request, the application will sleep.